# Can Apple Lossless audio be converted to FLAC with no loss of fidelity?

Tags: audio, conversion, flac, alac

Can Apple Lossless audio files (ALAC) be converted to FLAC audio files with no loss of fidelity?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, given that both are mathematically lossless, conversion is lossless too.

The reason for this is that the signal can always be reconstructed to its original form when a FLAC/ALAC file is decoded. Thus, they are equivalent and you should experience no loss when transcoding — even when transcoding multiple times.

The only error I could imagine would be an arithmetical one, e.g. through limited floating point precision in calculations. I don't think this applies to either FLAC or ALAC.

In case you only use a "psychoacoustically" lossless codec, this is not possible. Lossless in a psychoacoustic sense would mean that you can't distinguish the original and the compressed version, yet they are very different from each other. MP3 or MPEG-4 AAC use various psychoacoustic techniques to achieve this. Thus, when transcoding, the original version can't be reconstructed and you'd experience a loss of quality.

---

In case you want to convert ALAC to FLAC, [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) would be a good option, as it's free and available for almost every platform.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.m4a -c:a flac audio.flac
```

FFmpeg will read ALAC without issues. For *nix systems, there's also a script called [Convert to FLAC](http://legroom.net/software/convtoflac) which makes the whole process easier. With Bash you could simply convert all files in a single directory as well:

```
for f in *.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a flac "${f%.m4a}.flac"; done
```

<sub>**Note:** If you get a message about `ffmpeg` being deprecated, this is actually not the case – it's still an actively developed program. However, Ubuntu's package maintainers just decided to switch to the Libav fork of FFmpeg and thus supply you with `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg`. The version of `ffmpeg`  available on Ubuntu is therefore outdated. You can get a recent one by [downloading a static build instead](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), or compiling it yourself. Read on for more info: [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv)</sub>

Comment: Based on http://superuser.com/a/277358/45914, you can do the following to convert an entire directory:

`for f in *.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec flac "${f%.m4a}.flac"; done`

This works on Linux, but also in a Git bash on Windows, for example.

Comment: Converting using ffmpeg, as @RuudvA said, works but gives me a message that says: `*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.`

In order to do this using aconv, do this instead:

`for f in *.m4a; do avconv -i "$f" "${f%.m4a}.flac"; done`

Comment: XLD is another good one for OSX.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows CMD you can do.

```
@for /R %%x in (*.m4a) do ffmpeg -i "%%x" -acodec flac "%%~dpnx.flac"
```

(Batch Script)

( This will do Recursion ( Every Folder and under from where its run ))

Answer (score 2):

for Windows in Powershell (using ffmpeg) you can do this to convert alac to flac:

`Get-ChildItem . -filter *.m4a| ForEach-Object { ffmpeg -i "$_" -acodec flac "$($_.basename).flac" }`

and conversely do this to convert to alac

`Get-ChildItem . -filter *.flac | ForEach-Object { ffmpeg -i "$_" -acodec alac $($_.basename).m4a" }`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac (since you have ALAC files), you could also use the open source software Max as nice frontend to do the conversion from and to ALAC/FLAC or many other formats..

Comment: Another nice one is XLD.